# There is no registered service of type <ClassName>

Tags: dependency-injection, blazor

I need to have communication between 2 components. I created a class that goes:

```
public interface IApplicationState
{
    string PlateNumber { get; }

    event Action OnPlateInput;

    void SetPlateNumber(string plateNumber);
}

public class ApplicationState : IApplicationState
{
    public string? PlateNumber { get; private set; }

    public event Action OnPlateInput;

    public void SetPlateNumber(string plateNumber)
    {
        PlateNumber = plateNumber;
        NotifyPlateNumberChanged();
    }

    private void NotifyPlateNumberChanged() => OnPlateInput?.Invoke();
}
```

Then registered it in my Program.cs

```
builder.Services.AddScoped(sp => new HttpClient
{
    BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress)
});
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IApplicationState, ApplicationState>();
```

Then called it in 2 of my components:

```
public partial class SideWidgetComponent : ComponentBase
{
    [Inject] ApplicationState ApplicationState { get; set; }
    private string _plateNUmber = string.Empty;

    public async Task SetPlateNumber()
    {
        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            if (_plateNUmber == string.Empty) return;
            ApplicationState?.SetPlateNumber(_plateNUmber);
        });
    }
}

partial class PlateListComponent : ComponentBase
{
    [Inject] private HttpClient? HttpClient { get; set; }
    [Inject] private ApplicationState ApplicationState { get; set; }
    
    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        ApplicationState.OnPlateInput += ApplicationState_OnPlateInput;
    }
}
```

When I start the program I get an error of

> Cannot provide a value for property 'ApplicationState' on type 'ALPR_WebUi.Client.Pages.HomeComponents.PlateListComponent'. There is no registered service of type 'ALPR_WebUi.Shared.ApplicationState'.

Answer (score 0):

You have registered the **interface** `IApplicationState` in `Program.cs`, but are trying to inject `ApplicationState`, ie the concrete type. Since you didn't register the concrete type, it doesn't know how to resolve it.

So, either register the concrete type (ie `ApplicationState` without the `I`) or inject the interface. Either way will work.